# Is a plane wave necessarily monochromatic?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, frequency, linear-systems, plane-wave

1. Is the expression $$\psi(x,t)=A\exp{i(kx-\omega t)}, \hspace{0.3cm}A=\rm constant$$ the most general form of the [plane wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave)?
2. If yes, does it mean that a plane wave is necessarily monochromatic?
3. If not, what is an example of a monochromatic wave that is not a plane wave? What is an example plane wave that is not monochromatic?
4. If the answer of (1) is in negative, what is the most general form of a plane wave?

Comment: Take the arbitrary function $f(t, \boldsymbol{x}) = f(\omega \, t - \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{x})$.  This is a *plane wave*, but it is NOT *monochromatic* since it can be analyzed by Fourier decomposition as a sum of exponentials (i.e monochromatic plane waves).  The $\omega$ entering that function is just an "effective" or "average" angular frequency, or a parameter if you prefer.

Comment: @Someone What is your definition of a plane wave?

Comment: A plane wave has **planar front waves**.  The argument $u = \omega \, t - \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{x}$ defines a plane oriented in space (from the wave vector $\boldsymbol{k}$).  So the function I gave above defines an infinity of parallel planes, or if you prefer a unique plane at location $\boldsymbol{x}$ and time $t$.  The plane wave is *monochromatic* only if $f(u)$ reduces to a sinusoidal function ; $f(u) = \sin{u}$ or $f(u) = \cos{u}$ (or equivalently $f(u) \propto e^{i u}$).

Comment: @Someone If the wave $A\cos(\omega t-\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r})$ has to be both plane and monochromatic, should we require $A$ to  be independent of both $\textbf{r}$ and $t$?

Comment: yes $A$ should be a constant to define a *monochromatic* wave.  If $A$ is a function of $u = \omega \, t - \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{x}$ (to have a *plane* wave), then you could analyse it (i.e. decompose) as a Fourier superposition of monochromatic functions (i.e sinusoidal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a plane wave is a wave with a planar phase front, which implies more than one spatial dimension. Typically, we would speak about plane waves in three dimensions. It also implies that the phase front is well defined, which requires it to be monochromatic. In that case the expression you provide is not the most general expression for a plane wave. Instead one would express it as 
$$\psi({\bf x},t)=\exp(i\omega t - i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf x}) , $$
where ${\bf k}$ is the propagation vector.

As such it is monochromatic. I can imagine that one can compose a wave consisting of a spectrum of such monochromatic plane waves, all propagating in the same direction, but wiht different frequencies. However, whether that would still represent a plane wave is not certain, because the phase may be ill-defined for such a polychromatic wave.

One can construct various types of waves that are monochromatic, but not plane waves. The only condition is that they have a fixed frequency. All such waves can be composed as a superposition of plane wave all having the same frequency. One example is the [Gaussian beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam), which is a solution of the [paraxial wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Paraxial_approximation)
$$ \nabla_{xy}^2 \psi({\bf x}) + i 2 k \partial_z \psi({\bf x}) = 0 . $$
Note that the equation contains the wave number $k=\omega/c$ as a parameter, which means that for a specific value of this parameter, the frequency is fixed. Hence, solutions of this paraxial wave equation are monochromatic fields.

Comment: What is an example of a monochromatic wave that is not a plane wave? @flippiefanus

Comment: @SRS for example a [Gaussian beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) or a [spherical wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Spherical_waves)

Comment: Why is any function $f(\omega t-\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r})$ is not a plane wave (as pointed out by @Someone)?  At any instant of time $t_0$ the wavefront is given by the equation 
 $\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}=\omega t_0+C={ C^\prime}$. where $C, C^\prime$ are constants. This is the equation of the locus of points in the same phase and it represents a plane. @flippiefanus

Comment: A wavefront is a set of points with the same phase. For an arbitrary function with $\omega t-{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}$ as argument, the latter does not necessarily represent a phase.